# Cannot install Ubuntu after uninstalling

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

As a Windows user, I felt like I needed to get more into Ubuntu a few months back. I installed it as a dual boot alongside Windows 10. After a couple of days of struggling to install my nvidia driver, I decided to reinstall Ubuntu. So I deleted the partition from from windows, and used the Master Boot Record fix thingy. Now I want to give another shot to Ubuntu, but I cannot install it.

During installation, on the "select partition" windows, when I click continue, installer gives an error without any error code to search for. It gives an error about "ubiquity". I tried pretty much every possible solution regarding Ubuntu install/uninstall but couldn't figure it out. I have absolutely no experience with Ubuntu/Linux, so I cannot figure out where the problem lies (Grub, partition etc), so I cannot search with the correct keywords.

Can any of you guys help me live about this situation. Such as over whatsapp or telegram, so I can send you the screenshots/photos of the installation screen and the errors?

screenshots and photos: [http://imgur.com/a/3eWrU](https://imgur.com/a/3eWrU)

Note: I installed the 16.04 LTS version, and my laptop is an ASUS N550JK

Comment: Hopefully you didn't enabled "dynamic disks" or whatever in Windows, did you?

Comment: I will check it now, but if I enabled it somehow, is it bad?

Comment: I checked and all the partitions are labeled as "Basic", you can see from the first screen shot in the album.

Comment: It's a Microsoft's proprietary technology not supported in Linux so yes, bad. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363785(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Got it, but like I said all my partition are labeled as "Basic".

Comment: OK, assuming it's basic then it should work. You need to boot in UEFI mode though because your Windows is also in that mode, therefore select the entry preceded by "UEFI" for the USB drive. Also disable fast startup in Windows and shutdown (reboot often reverts the settings) before booting Ubuntu.

Comment: I already tried that, but I tried that again just now. After hitting the "continue" button on the partition window, it throws an "internal error" which can be seen on the image(http://imgur.com/DClcYl6). After this window a black screen appears. (http://imgur.com/Mr7dtrl)

Comment: Somehow your screenshot of the error doesn't match the one from Windows. I mean, it doesn't like the same drive. You may need to manually create partitions.Please tell me if you need help with that.

Comment: I will need help with that, but before that I have another question. On the partition window, installer tries to create the partition from C:, but I want it to carve the partition from D:. How can I do that or can I do that?

Comment: You should shrink Windows partitions directly from Windows. And if it allows it, also move the current "C:" and the others to the left so the currently unallocated 900MB are at the end of the drive, which will make things easier and is a better use of space. I'm not sure that can be done with the standard (native) Windows disk management tool (but it should be). Important: Reboot to Windows to let it run the error correction tool.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I solved the problem and posting it here for future reference. I wiped all the partitions I could and merged them with Windows partitions. After that I did a clean dual-boot installation and it worked.